# Magento 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 issue with special price

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have fond a bug on **Magento CE 1.8.0** and **1.8.1** that is related to special price.

If I set some special price on product and save that change, magento sets current date for `Set Product as New from Date` (news_from_date), `Special Price From Date` (special_from_date) and `Active From` (custom_design_from). After these values are set I'm unable to remove them both grammatically and using admin panel.

Has anyone found reason for this issue and how to fix it.

P.S. This was ok on CE 1.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a real bug, which a had in every update 1.8 and 1.8.1. This is the (temporarely) solution. I found it here:

http://www.sdms.it/magento-1-8-new-date-bug/

Apply the module found here: http://www.multibyte.at/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Multibyte_DateFix.zip

After uploading, flushing cache and logout / login the problem is fixed.

Comment: This code i have apply on magento-1.8.1.0 but this was not warking how to fix this issue.

Comment: In the more recent magento verslons, notably the 1.9.x versions, the issue is fixed. So you don't have to patch anything. If you already "fixed it" reverse the code, e.g. override it with the original one

Answer (score 0):

Try

$product->setData('news_from_date', FALSE);

It works for me.