# Installing module via Package Error

Tags: magento

I try to apply module to fix the special price issue follow this: [Magento 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 issue with special price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570528/magento-1-8-0-and-1-8-1-issue-with-special-price)

But i find error as below when trying to install the module. Any Advice please?

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that a package.xml parsing error due to invalid XML will result in that same error message.

If you are packaging your module yourself you should use tar:

1. CD into the root directory of your extension (Where your package.xml is located)
2. run: `tar -cvzf MyModule.tgz app package.xml skin` (and other files/dirs if applicable)

Comment: i am getting 
CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type

Answer (score 1):

The extension file from the link you posted is not a prepackaged module you can install using the Magento Connect method.  You must unzip the folder and drag & drop the files into the root directory of your Magento install.

For the extension to be installable using the Connect method, it must include a package.xml file within the zip container.